# jshint, eqnull, Use '===' to compare with 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jshint

I apologize ahead of time, I am clearly utterly incapable of understanding how to configure jshint.

I have this line of code

```
if ( data == undefined || (typeof data === 'object' && data.length === 0) ) {
...
```

jshint is underlining the first `==` and saying

> Use '===' to compare with 'undefined'.

I added `/* jshint eqnull:true */`. I thought this is what the option does. I even see [an example here](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) (search for eqnull).

What am I missing?

Comment: `eqnull` suppresses the warning about comparing with `null`, not `undefined`.

Comment: Is it possible to suppress the warning about `undefined`?

Comment: I don't see any mention of such a thing in the documentation.

Comment: If you use " typeof data == 'undefined' "  instead of " data == undefined ", no warning message will be shown. You don't need to suppress warning when no warning is displayed.

Comment: I'd like to use `== undefined` to coerce null to undefined. `typeof null` is object.

Answer (score 6):

Use this option for the same

"-W041": false

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, `undefined` and `null` are two distinct values. Directly comparing other values to `undefined` is problematic, because `null == undefined`, but `typeof null != typeof undefined`.

From your comment above, it seems that you explicitly want to check for both `null` and `undefined` values, in which case you could write `(data === undefined || data === null)`.

If you are keen to keep a shorter expression, you could just write `data == null`, which is functionally identical. As you mention above, you will need to provide the `/* jshint eqnull:true */` option.